# how to change Git Bash options for terminal to xterm-256color

Tags: git, cmd, git-bash

I want to change the color of the bash but I dont know how to.

I tried with right clicking the bash but this just gave me the properties. Here a screenshot of my git bash: [image: my console]

Comment: Is git bash for windows?

Comment: @trisquel take a look on path, this is definitely a Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Git Bash on Windows you can changue color with these steeps:

- Open a Git bash windows and click on the upper left corner of the windows frame.
- In the menu that will be appear click on **Properties -> Colors** and check **Screen Text** and remenber the color that is currently assigned to this checkbox.
- Select the new color clicking on the color box.
- Change the Blue/Red/Green values for the selected color.
- **Screen Text** checkbox is now still the color so click on the original color that you have remembered.

> The changes are permanent and only for the shortcut you have used to start Git Bash.

Comment: i want to change the type of color as i mentioned in title i want bash to support the ANSI colors i want to change it to xterm-256color
this

Answer (score 1):

this worked for Laravel 6. *

```
composer require symfony/console:4.3.4
```

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot in the question suggests it is about "Git Bash" (Windows specific, see https://gitforwindows.org/).

For some reasons I had once to explicitly set the `TERM` environment variable to the value `xterm`. That broke the output in "Git Bash" sessions which were started embedded in IntelliJ IDEA ("Terminal" tool), exactly like described in the posted question. The solution was to set the `TERM` environment variable either to `xterm-256color` (!) or to the default value (default for "Git Bash"), which is `cygwin`.

Small before/after example:
[image]

If you need/want to permanently set the new value for the `TERM` environment variable, the best solution would be to add `export TERM=xterm-256color` to your `~/.bashrc` file.